postgres stuck on a time type column comparison
I am using a query to left join table a with cms on common columns and doing a time comparison like this:
a.col1=cms.col1 and
a.col2=cms.col2 and 
to_char(a.job_time::timestamp, 'HH24:MI:SS')::time
 between (cms.scheduled_load_start-interval '1.5 hours')
     and (cms.scheduled_load_finish+interval '2 hours')

I get the run no from cms table but somehow only one record out of 2000 is not falling between the scheduled start and finish even though it should. I am not able to understand.
The a.job_time has a value of 01:00:38 and scheduled start and end have 00:00:00 and 01:00:00. If I add and subtract interval then the job_time should return run no but its returning null, not joining with the cms table because of the time part, col1 and col2 are joining without any issue.

Why the strange to_char followed by a cast back to time? Your description is not very clear. If language fails you, perhaps you can add sample data and SQL to make your problem clear.

Are job_time, scheduled_load_start, scheduled_load_finish all stored in time fields in the database?  If so how do deal with time ranges that cross Midnight?

Sorry about not writing in clear language but i have resolved the issue by removing the -interval 1.5 hours from scheduled start time...i think it was failing due to some conversion thing. I am using tochar to extract the time portion from timestamp column and then converting it into time because i can't compare text type with time type

Although removing -interval '1.5 hours' produced the desired results for the specific case, it doesn't address the fundamental issues caused by applying linear approaches to what is essentially modular math. There is also a potential issue with using closed intervals since a.job_time could potentially belong to two contiguous comparison ranges. Time ranges are usually handled as half-open intervals where lower <= value < upper.

Please see [mre]. Please update the post with table DDL, example data, and expected results. When working with time related values, it is very important to know the data type of the referenced columns. Constraints on the data values are also important.
